# scala -- can't import class from manually created jar, only eclipse-created runnable jar

Tags: class, scala, import, jar

The Scala prompt lets me use my Java class when it's within an Eclipse project-turned-runnable-jar, but not otherwise.  How to get around this?  I saw another SO answer saying to use sbt, but why does it work with the one jar and not the other? And how do I make it work with my .class or manually created .jar?

Using the command:
`scala -cp ./MyClass.class` :

`scala> import package.name.MyClass`
`<console>:7: error: not found: value  package`
Ok, let's jar it... 
`jar -cvf MyJar.jar MyClass.class`
 `scala -cp ./MyJar.jar`:
... same result. 
Alright... `scala -cp path/to/runnable_jar/created/from/eclipse.jar` 

`scala> import package.name.MyClass` 
It works!

Comment: Just to be sure I'd like to point out that `package` is a reserved word.

Comment: thanks -- perhaps poorly chosen for this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at how that Eclipse-created jar file is arranged (with jar tf), and compare it with yours. Most likely the package path is wrong.

> jar -cvf MyJar.jar MyClass.class

This won't work, because you need to preserve the package path as directories inside the jar.

Should be `jar -cvf MyJar.jar package`.

> scala -cp ./MyClass.class

This won't work, because classpath must point to folders with classes (starting at the package root folder) or to jar files.

Should be `scala -cp classes` (and classes has a folder "package").